# Unable to log into elastic search

Tags: docker, elasticsearch

I am trying to set up Filebeats/Elasticsearch/Kibana to monitor log files for my application.

I have the fairly minimal compose show below.

When I go to localhost:19200, I was able to get elastic search responses before I enabled security.  Now, it prompts me to sign in.  However, neither `elastic` and `change` nor `kibana` and `changeme` are accepted.

Attempting to change the password with `curl` by

```
curl  -XPOST -u elastic:changeme 'localhost:19200/_security/user/elastic/_password' -H "Content-Type: application/json" -d "{
  \"password\" : \"insecure\"
}"
```

also fails with an authentication error.

From the server log, the error is

`elasticsearch_1  | {"type": "server", "timestamp": "2019-09-16T20:59:06,588+0000", "level": "INFO", "component": "o.e.x.s.a.AuthenticationService", "cluster.name": "compass", "node.name": "node-1", "cluster.uuid": "RZ_T1pT5Tp--3Jm8q89NVw", "node.id": "Q-lFQ58gRGOPPOEyzy6Vrw",  "message": "Authentication of [elastic] was terminated by realm [reserved] - failed to authenticate user [elastic]"  }`

The JSON returned to `curl` is

`{"error":{"root_cause":[{"type":"security_exception","reason":"failed to authenticate user [elastic]","header":{"WWW-Authenticate":"Basic realm=\"security\" charset=\"UTF-8\""}}],"type":"security_exception","reason":"failed to authenticate user [elastic]","header":{"WWW-Authenticate":"Basic realm=\"security\" charset=\"UTF-8\""}},"status":401}`

What am I doing wrong?

**docker-compose.yml**

```
version: "2.4"

services:
  # Accumulate logs into elasticstack
  elasticsearch:
    image: "docker.elastic.co/elasticsearch/elasticsearch:${ELASTIC_VERSION}"
    environment:
      - http.host=0.0.0.0
      - transport.host=127.0.0.1
      - bootstrap.memory_lock=true
      - "ES_JAVA_OPTS=-Xms${ES_JVM_HEAP} -Xmx${ES_JVM_HEAP}"
    mem_limit: ${ES_MEM_LIMIT}
    ulimits:
      memlock:
        soft: -1
        hard: -1
    volumes:
      - ./config/elasticsearch/elasticsearch.yml:/usr/share/elasticsearch/config/elasticsearch.yml
      - data:/usr/share/elasticsearch/data

      #Port 9200 is available on the host. Need to for user to access as well as Packetbeat
    ports: ['19200:9200']
    #Healthcheck to confirm availability of ES. Other containers wait on this.
    healthcheck:
      test: ["CMD", "curl","-s" ,"-f", "-u", "elastic:${ES_PASSWORD}", "http://localhost:9200/_cat/health"]
    #Internal network for the containers
    networks: ['stack']

volumes:
  #Es data
  data:
    driver: local
networks: {stack: {}}
```

**.env**

```
#ELK Stack
ELASTIC_VERSION=7.3.2
ES_PASSWORD=insecure
ES_MEM_LIMIT=2g
ES_JVM_HEAP=1024m
```

**config/elasticsearch/elasticsearch.yml**

```
cluster.name: compass
node.name: node-1
path.data: /usr/share/elasticsearch/data
http.port: 9200
network.host: 0.0.0.0
xpack.security:
  enabled: true
  transport.ssl.enabled: true
```

Comment: 19200???? you should use localhost:9200

Comment: Not if the compose maps port 9200 inside the container to 19200 on the localhost.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should set up the built-in user passwords when you enable security, using

```
./bin/elasticsearch-setup-passwords interactive
```

See https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elastic-stack-overview/current/get-started-built-in-users.html

Comment: I was basing my compose on the full_stack_example at https://github.com/elastic/examples/tree/master/Miscellaneous/docker/full_stack_example, which looks like an official Elastic repository.  Is that no longer a useful example?

Comment: Possibly not. It's version 5.5 which is a couple of years old.

Comment: Is there a way to run that from a script?  The best that I can see is to run `elasticsearch-setup-passwords auto`, save the output to a file and then parse it.  And then I still have to get it out of the docker container.